# Trying to create buttons for converting Fahrenheit and Celsius

Tags: javascript, html, data-conversion

```js
var typeTemp = document.getElementById("demo3");

document.getElementById("f").addEventListener("click", function(){
    var tValue = parseFloat(typeTemp.value); // allows the number to be functional
    
    document.getElementById("Fanswer").innerHTML = (1.8 * tValue) + 32;
});

document.getElementById("c").addEventListener("click", function(){
    var tValue = parseFloat(typeTemp.value); // allows the number to be functional
    
    document.getElementById("Canswer").innerHTML = 1.8 * (tValue - 32);
});
```

```html
   <input type="number" id="demo3" class="ex" min=0><br>
        <button id="f">Fahrenheit</button>
        <div id="Fanswer"></div>
        <button id="c">Celsius</button>
        <div id="Canswer"></div>
```

Hi, I am trying to make the Fahrenheit and Celsius buttons work and make the answers show up in the div. I have no errors when I inspect but I do get "NaN" for both functions. I am not sure why it is doing that :( Thank you.

Comment: You have to get the variable value in your click event. Don't forgot to get the value of your input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're using `typeTemp` as a value when it actually is a DOM node, you should edit it like this:

```
var typeTemp = document.getElementById("demo3");

document.getElementById("f").addEventListener("click", function(){
    var tValue = parseFloat(typeTemp.value); // allows the number to be functional

    document.getElementById("Fanswer").innerHTML = (1.8 * tValue) + 32;
});

document.getElementById("c").addEventListener("click", function(){
    var tValue = parseFloat(typeTemp.value); // allows the number to be functional

    document.getElementById("Canswer").innerHTML = 1.8 * (tValue - 32);
});
```

Comment: @YongJunJung I'll suggest you to learn from MDN documentation, just right here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web

Answer (score 1):

`typeTemp` is a reference to the DOM element, but you're using it as though it were a string (the element's value). You want to use its `.value` property, see `***` comments:

```js
var typeTemp = document.getElementById("demo3");

document.getElementById("f").addEventListener("click", function(){
    var tValue = parseFloat(typeTemp.value); // ***
    
    document.getElementById("Fanswer").innerHTML = (1.8 * tValue) + 32;
});

document.getElementById("c").addEventListener("click", function(){
    var tValue = parseFloat(typeTemp.value); // ***
    
    document.getElementById("Canswer").innerHTML = 1.8 * (tValue - 32);
});
```

```html
<input type="number" id="demo3" class="ex"><br>
        <button id="f">Fahrenheit</button>
        <div id="Fanswer"></div>
        <button id="c">Celsius</button>
        <div id="Canswer"></div>
```

The reason you were getting `NaN` is a bit complicated, but:

- `parseFloat` will try to coerce what you give it to string
- You were giving it a DOM element
- When you coerce a DOM element to string, typically you get a string like `"[object HTMLInputElement]"`
- `parseFloat` returns `NaN` if it can't convert even just the first part of the string you gave it to number, which it can't in the case of `"[object HTMLInputElement]"`

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining in detail. ! I will remember this.